# How do I clear a way point?

Tags: no-mans-sky

While viewing endless void of the Galactic Map, I accidentally set a way point to a star system that would take me too long to get to.

Other than visiting the way point's location, is there any way I can clear way point? I currently have not set an option to so this

Comment: Haven't played around in the map all that much - but could you replace it with a new waypoint where you are?

Comment: To anyone googling this when it just happened, I solved it by restarting the game (which reloads the save). I imagine it doesn't work if you saved before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no ability to remove way points in the Galaxy map other than visiting them. A huge design flaw, but hopefully something that will be fixed in a later patch.

Comment: One of my waypoints disappeared the second-to-last time I shut the game down.  That is, the most recent time I loaded the game, a waypoint I had set 4-5 days ago was simply gone.  It just so happened that I wanted to get rid of that particular waypoint, so it was a good thing.  But I wonder what would have happened if I had had other waypoints that I wanted to keep ...

Answer (score -2):

If by waypoints you mean like a shelter, manufacturing facility etc... Then you can clear them, yes. The only way to do so is to warp to another Solar System. You can not clear them by going to any menus or anything like that, they stay on your screen for as long as you are exploring that Solar System.

Comment: The question specifically says it's referring to solar systems in the Galactic Map.